# Count visible divs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

HTML:

```
<div class="male">...</div>
<div class="male">...</div>
<div class="female">...</div>
```

I have several divs with categories as class (and more divs without `.male` inside of them), on startup I count them with

```
$('.male').size(); // Returns 40 items for example
```

*(I know `size();` is deprecated but we use an older version of jQuery)*

During the application, some of the divs turn invisible after a specific click,
I want to recount the **visible** items.

I tried

```
$('.male :visible').size();
```

But it gave me a horrible high number, like 3050, so I assume the selector does count all the visible divs inside `.male` or something.

**Is someone able to advice me the correct selector for only visible divs with specific class?**

Comment: You are collecting ALL the elements (not only divs) inside the .male container. What about $('div.male:visible').size() ?

Comment: Even older versions contain `.length`, don't they? ;)

Comment: @ThiefMaster I tried with `.length()` and it did give me an error, I left a comment about that in the sources, in case.. :-)

Comment: It's a property, not a method.

Comment: @ThiefMaster thanks for the advice, changed my code and it works with `.length`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to remove the space between `.male` and `:visible`, otherwise you're targeting all visible elements *within* `.male`:

```
$('.male:visible').size();
```

[Here's a quick JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/gMvLW/) showing both.

**UPDATE:** jQuery 1.8 deprecated its `size()` method in favour of using JavaScript's `length` property instead. We can now:

```
$('.male:visible').length;
```

Answer (score 8):

Remove the space from your selector:

```
$('.male:visible').size();
```